# Ассемблер, Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction

Tags: ассемблер, nasm, sasm

Есть код на ассемблере nasm:

```
mov edx, hello
mov ah, 09h
hello db 'Hello world$'
int 21h
xor eax, eax
```

При запуске в SASM получаю ошибку **Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction** конкретно на строке `hello db 'Hello world$'`. Пробовал менять местами её со строкой `int 21h`, но тогда ошибка кидалась на строку `int 21h`. Что мне поменять, или как вывести на экран строку в SASM?

p.s. Если ошибка очень тупая, не судите строго, пожалуйста, я такой-же тупой

Comment: Это программа для DOS, она не будет работать ни под Windows, ни под Linux.

Comment: `или как вывести на экран строку в SASM?` - смотрите те примеры, что идут с SASM.

Comment: Спасибо, я что-то совсем затупил, думал, что в sasm стандартный ассемблер будет работать) Сейчас всё переделал, заработало

Comment: int 21h - это не "стандартный" ассемблер уже лет 20 (хотя вообще нет такой вещи, как "стандартный ассемблер", потому что нет стандарта). В целом, не любая программа на ассеблере, найденная в интернете, заработает на вашей системе. Вот такие программы с использованием прерываний без эмулятора DOS не заработают, и это не в SASM проблема.

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз, но тогда где учить ассемблер, если почти во всех мануалах и статьях говорится про int 21h? Книгу мб, или курс, если не сложно)

Comment: Если просто интересуетесь ассемблером, а не изучаете в ВУЗе, значит у вас есть выбор - ищите примеры конкретно под вашу операционную систему (так по крайней мере вам будет проще запускать - без эмуляторов и виртуалок). Под Windows могу посоветовать самоучители по ассемблеру Крупника А.Б. 2005 года (old but gold, как говорится).

Answer (score 0):

ты размещаешь строку внутри исполняемого кода, в определённый момент процессор пытается "выполнить" ее как команду.

раздели секцию кода и секцию данных

как разделить ищи сам, это не сложно.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы вытащили этот кусок кода из примера для DOS - об этом говорит то, что в нем используется прерывание `int 21h`. Даже если поправить другие проблемы в этом коде, программа с использованием такого прерывания не будет работать на современных операционных системах (без эмулятора).

За основу программ для SASM проще брать те примеры, которые идут вместе с этой IDE.